# more than one value selected in a picklist

Tags: multi-select

I am trying to write a trigger or wf for a field to be updated if a Multi-select picklist has more than one value.  Any suggestions on how to write if the multi-select has more than one value

Comment: In Apex you can [split](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split) the field on ';' (the separator used in multi-select picklist selections) and check the size of the result.

Comment: Depending on the length of the Multi-select, you could also assess the content of the field for actual values.  However, that would also require modifications to the trigger every time a new value is added to the the list.

Answer (score 2):

As Keith C and HomerJ said you can write something like this. Hope this helps.

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    
    for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){ 

        // MultiSelect Fields are a single String with values delimited by a semi-colon
        // DeliveryInstallationStatus__c is a Picklist (Multi-Select)
        String[] deliveryArray = opp.DeliveryInstallationStatus__c.split(';');
        if(deliveryArray.size()>0){
            // Write your logic here
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiselect Picklist values are de-limited by a semi-colon ";" .To get expected result, add the field values to a string/list and split the string/list to get the count of multiselect picklist values.
Below example shows a Opportunity Trigger to get the count of multiselect picklist values.

```
    if(Trigger.isupdate || Trigger.isinsert){

         for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){

            system.debug('----MultiSelect Picklist Values----'+ opp.OpportunityProductLog__c);
            List<String> lstOpportunityMultiselectPicklist = opp.OpportunityProductLog__c.split(';');
            system.debug('----List Size ----'+ lstOpportunityMultiselectPicklist .size());
            if(!lstOpportunityMultiselectPicklist.isEmpty() && lstOpportunityMultiselectPicklist.size() > 1)
            {
                //Code
            }
         }
    }
```